# FirebaseError: Expected type 'vc', but it was: a custom rn object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from Firestore by using react-firebase-hooks: v5.0.3 but I keep getting the aforementioned error. I've also tried using onSnapshot but surely, the same error pops up. I've also tried importing `collection` and `getFirestore` from `"firebase/firestore/"` instead of `"firebase/firestore/lite"`, but that pops up another error `expected first argument to collection() to be a collectionreference, a documentreference or firebasefirestore`.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./css/Sidebar.module.css";
import {
  ChatAltIcon,
  CubeTransparentIcon,
  DotsVerticalIcon,
  SearchIcon,
  UserCircleIcon,
  XIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import * as EmailValidator from "email-validator";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { onSnapshot, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

function Sidebar() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
   const q = query(collection(db,"chats"),where("users", "array-contains", user.email));
  //  const [chatsSnapshot, loading, error] = useCollection(q); //same issue, 
  // console.log("ChatSnapshot error: ", error); //console logging "error" logs "undefined".
  let data;
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q,(querySnapshot)=>{
    data = querySnapshot.data;
  });
  console.log(data); 
  unsubscribe();


  const createChat = () => {
    const input = prompt(
      "Please enter email address of the user you wish to chat with."
    );

    if (!input) return null;

    if (
      EmailValidator.validate(input) &&
      input !== user.email &&
      !chatAllReadyExists(input)
    ) {
      //add chat to db if it already doesnt exist and also validate
      addDoc(collection(db, "chats"), { users: [user.email, input] }).then(
        (res) => console.log("doc added ", res)
      );
    }
  };

  const chatAllReadyExists = (recipentEmail) =>
    !!chatsSnapshot?.docs.find(
      (chat) =>
        chat.data().users.find((user) => user === recipentEmail)?.length > 0
    );

  const userSignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth).then((res) => {
      console.log("You have been logged out!");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.sidebarBlock}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <UserCircleIcon className={classes.user} onClick={userSignOut} />
        <span className={classes.flexContainer}>
          <CubeTransparentIcon className={classes["button"]} />
          <ChatAltIcon onClick={createChat} className={classes["button"]} />
          <DotsVerticalIcon className={classes["button"]} />
        </span>
      </div>

      <div className={classes.searchBoxContainer}>
        <SearchIcon className={classes.button} />
        <input
          className={classes.searchBar}
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search or start new chat"
        />
        <XIcon className={classes.button} />
      </div>

      <div className={classes.contactList}>
        <ul className={classes.listContainer}>
          <li className={classes.listItem}>
            <UserCircleIcon className={classes.user} />
            <div className={classes.descContainer}>
              <h3>Person's Name</h3>
              <p>Last chat to read</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

> Firebase.js

```
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
};
let app;
if (getApps().length < 1) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Comment: Can you share your firebase.js where you initialize Firebase?

Comment: Hi, I've pasted the firebase.js code under the main code.